# Export asset as jpg from Zeplin

Tags: sketchapp, zeplin

it may seem a silly question but ...
How Can I Export in jpg format from zeplin ? I even tried to change the format png to jpg in the dialog box sketch and when I export the artboard to zeplin still the option to export as PNG

Comment: I have the same problem. For now I'm exporting those JPG individually from Sketch

Answer (score 1):

Zeplin just added JPG support on [1.9](https://twitter.com/zeplin_io/status/785864198060408832). When you export assets that contain bitmap layers, Zeplin should automatically generate the JPG versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop a screen from screen list.

Like on this  [GIF](https://uploads.intercomcdn.com/i/o/24190204/a9e68ae9f65b0138640cce96/drag.gif) :